# Error: invalid solidity type!: decimal10

Tags: solidity, web3js

I'm getting the error

```
Error: invalid solidity type!: decimal10
```

when making a call to my contract using web3.js

I believe it enters this in web3/lib/solidity/coder.js

```
SolidityCoder.prototype._requireType = function (type) {
var solidityType = this._types.filter(function (t) {
    return t.isType(type);
})[0];

if (!solidityType) {
    throw Error('invalid solidity type!: ' + type);
}

  return solidityType;
};
```

Where the type isn't found, is there a way to overcome this issue?

Comment: What version of web3 are you using?